# detectar el idioma del navegador con js y redirigir al visitante

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola Necesito que cuando un usuario abra mi sitio web, detecte el idioma y lo redireccione al idioma del navegador. Estoy intentando esto pero entra en un bucle y la página se carga constantemente. Espero que puedas ayudar.son 3 idiomas a los que tengo que dirigir: aleman,español e ingles.

```
window.onload = function () {

   var ln = window.navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;

   if (ln == 'de') {

     window.location.href = 'indexDe.html';

   } else if (ln == 'es') {

     window.location.href = 'indexEs.html';

   }más{

     window.location.href = 'indexEn.html';

   }

}
```

Comment: tienes este código en tus tres archivos index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La siguiente respuesta se aplica si en todos tus archivos index estas realizando esta misma verificación.**

El problema es que siempre estas realizando la verificación del idioma y re direccionamiento sin verificar si el usuario ya se encuentra en la pagina correspondiente a su idioma. En consecuencia se crea un bucle infinito de redirección. Para solucionar esto, puede obtener el **pathname** de la pagina en la que se encuentra y verificar que no sea la misma a la que estas por redirigir.

Lo puedes hacer del siguiente modo:

```js
    window.onload = function () {

   var ln = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
   /*Validar que no se encuentre en la pagina correspondiente a su idioma*/
   let pagActual = window.location.pathname;
   
   
   if (ln == 'en-EN' && !pagActual.includes("indexEn")) {
       window.location.href = 'indexEn.html';  
   } else if (ln == 'es-ES' && !pagActual.includes("indexEs")) {
       window.location.href = 'indexEs.html';
   } else if (ln == 'de-DE' && !pagActual.includes("indexDe")){
       window.location.href = 'indexDe.html';
   } else{
     console.log("Otro idioma");
   }

}
```

Comment: Hola Fran gracias por la respuesta una pregunta si como puedo hacer si por ejemplo quiero que se redireccione a Aleman o  español y que si el navegador no esta en aleman o  español por defecto se abra en ingles.puede ser asi :

Comment: todo seria igual pero en el ultimo }else if (ln == ' de-DE' || 'es-Es && !pagActual.includes ("indexDe",  "indexEs")){ window.location.href= 'indexEn.html'; }}

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que debería tu código trabajar de este modo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {

   var ln = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
   if (ln == 'en') {

     console.log("english")
     window.location.replace("indexEN.html");

   } else if (ln == 'es-419') {

     console.log("español")
     window.location.replace("indexES.html");
   }else if (ln == 'de-DE'){
     console.log("alemán")
     window.location.replace("indexDE.html");
   }else{
     console.log("desconocido")
   }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. Para obtener el lenguaje del navegador sería: `var ln = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;`
2. Para el caso del lenguaje inglés si es `en`
3. Para el caso del español la etiqueta debería ser: `es-419`
4. Para el caso del lenguale alemán debería ser: `de-DE`
5. Al estar usando `window.onload` este código entrará en funcionamiento en cuanto la página cargue, por lo que creo debería solo ir en una que redigija a cualquier otra

Lo que sucede es que por cada lenguaje existen variantes

Además de lo anterior deberías usar `window.location.replace` el cual sustituye el recurso actual por uno pasado como parámetro

```
window.location.replace("https://www.es.stackoverflow.com");
```

> Prueba usándolo por que no mantiene las páginas en historial

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema del bucle por el cual está consultando.